# Symbol font as icon in DataGridView

Tags: c#, image, datagridview, fonts, symbols

I am aware that in DataGridview, we can bind a ImageColumn to image data to display icon such as. Normally I would use icons from Microsoft's MsoImage.

[image]

It occurs to me that from symbol font, we can have many nice icons. Is it possible to bind the column to text instead, with fonts taken into account, so that we can make use of symbol font and display the result of **text + font** that looks like icons.

[image]

If text binding is not possible, is there another way of extracting/converting the symbol font into images?

Comment: You can set the Font in a `DataGridViewCellStyle.Font`. Databinding will only let you provide the character code but not affect the font, though..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to set the Font for the Column. Here is am example:

[image]

```
List<daz> dazz = new List<daz>() { new daz("♻", "267B"), new daz("⚔", "2694") };
Font f = new Font("Segue UI Symbol", 12f);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dazz;
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Font = f;
```

Ignore the example class:

```
class daz
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public daz (string c, string t) { code = c;  text = t; }
}
```